# Finding the constants so the integration formulas are accurate to an accuracy level of $3$

Tags: integration, analysis, statistics, numerical-methods

> $$\int^1_{-1}f(x)dx=af(-1)+bf(1)+cf'(-1)+df'(1)$$

I need to find constants so that the integration formulas are accurate to an accuracy level of $3$ (i.e. will give results identical to the true value for a polynomial of no more than $3$). I started to study this subject alone last week, and I got lost.

Any hints?

Comment: A polynomial of degree $3$ is uniquely determined the the four values $f(1), f'(1), f(-1), f'(-1)$. You can explicitly write down that polynomial in terms of those four values (a form of Hermite interpolation). Then you can integrate it from $-1$ to $1$. The result will also be in terms of the four values. This will tell you your constants.

Comment: @davidlowryduda♦  I'm not sure I understand your explain.

Comment: any help please ? or good explain that  i will understand from?

Comment: Let's break this down. First: explicitly write down the degree 3 polynomial in terms of the four values $f(1), f'(1), f(-1), f'(-1)$. There are good ways and bad ways to do this, but the most naive approach of calling it $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ and writing down the system of four linear equations coming from evaluating $f(1)$ (etc) will give a linear system of four equations in four unknowns --- and this works. You now have an explicit form $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, where $a,b,c,d$ are evaluated in terms of the prescribed values $f(1)$ (etc). Second: evaluate the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four degrees of freedom (corresponding to the four weights $a, b, c, d$). A cubic polynomial is determined by four pieces of information. Thus we should expect that doing this for a generic cubic polynomial will exactly uniquely determine the weights.

The rest of this answer will follow two steps:

1. There will be a unique cubic polynomial $F(x)$ having prescribed values at $-1$ and $1$, and with prescribed derivatives at $-1$ and $1$. We find this polynomial.
2. Integrate the above polynomial to find the weights.
3. (Bonus --- we'll check on an example)

### Finding the cubic polynomial with prescribed values

There are many ways of doing this, but I'm lazy and don't want to think of a convenient interpolation basis. So instead I'll use linear algebra. Consider a cubic polynomial of the form $F(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$. Form the matrix system whose rows are (in order) the equations $F(-1), F'(-1), F(1), F'(1)$. This system is then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
3 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A \\
B \\
C \\
D
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
F(-1) \\ F'(-1) \\ F(1) \\ F'(-1)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The solution to this system will be the unique polynomial $F$. Perhaps the easiest way to determine this is to note that the inverse of the matrix is
$$
\frac{1}{4} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
-3 & -1 & 3 & -1 \\
2 & 1 & 2 & -1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
and thus the solution is
$$
\begin{pmatrix} A \\ B \\ C \\ D \end{pmatrix} = 
\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix}
F(-1) + F'(-1) - F(1) + F'(1) \\
-F'(-1) + F'(1) \\
-3F(-1) - F'(-1) + 3F(1) - F'(1) \\
2F(-1) + F'(-1) + 2F(1) - F'(1) 
\end{pmatrix}. \tag{1}
$$

Let's make sure this is right by checking this on the arbitrary, made-up data $F(-1) = 1, F'(-1) = 2, F(1) = 3, F'(1) = 4$. Then this system indicates that the unique cubic polynomial satisfying these conditions is $F(x) = x^3 - x^2/2 + 3/2$, and a quick check confirms this.

### Integrating

In terms of the generic cubic $F(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$, we compute that
$$ \int_{-1}^1 F(x) dx = \frac{2B}{3} + 2D.$$
From $(1)$ above, we find that in terms of the values $F(-1), F'(-1), F(1), F'(1)$, this is
$$
F(-1) + \frac{1}{3}F'(-1) + F(1) - \frac{1}{3}F'(1). \tag{2}
$$

We claim that $(2)$ is perfect for cubic polynomials, and is our approximation for generic functions.

### Checking

Let's check on a variety of polynomials.

1. The constant $c$ polynomial has $f(-1) = f(1) = c$ and $f'(-1) = f'(1) = 0$. The integral is $2c$, and formula $(2)$ gives that it's approximately $c + 0 + c + 0 = 2c$. Good.
2. The polynomial $ax + c$ has $f(-1) = (c - a)$, $f(1) = (a + c)$, $f'(-1) = f'(1) = a$. The integral is $2c$ still. Formula $(2)$ gives that it's approximately $(c-a)  + (a/3) + (a + c) - (a/3) = 2c$. Good.
3. The polynomial $x^2 + 1$ has $f(-1) = f(1) = 2$, $f'(-1) = -2$, and $f'(1) = 2$. The integral is $8/3$. By $(2)$, we expect this to be $2 - 2/3 + 2 - 2/3 = 8/3$. Good.
4. The cubic $5x^3 + 3x^2 - x + 1$ has integral $4$. Then $f(-1) = 0, f(1) = 8, f'(-1) = 8, f'(1) = 20$, and $(2)$ indicates that the integral should be $0 + 8/3 + 8 - 20/3 = 4$. Good.

So this works out on lots of examples. For fun, let's also apply this to one case where it won't work without error. Consider the function $f(x) = e^x \sin x$. Then the integral over $[-1, 1]$ is actually about $0.6634$. The approximation $(2)$ indicates that the integral should be about
$$
f(-1) + f'(-1)/3 + f(1) - f'(1)/3 \approx
-0.3095 - 0.0369 + 2.2873 - 1.2520
\approx 0.6888,
$$
which is pretty close to the correct value of $0.6634$.

### Generalization and alternative method

I hope it's clear that this approach readily generalizes to general degree. There is a bit of linear algebra in the middle, but there's not much more to it.

However there is an alternative approach --- still linear algebra, but more direct. This argument should make it clear that the resulting approximation will be linear in the prescribed values. What this means is that if you choose *almost any four random cubic polynomials* (or polynomials of an appropriate power more generally), compute the relevant values of the polynomial and its derivative, set up a linear system from these random polynomials, and solve --- then you'll also find the weights (unless by some unlucky coincidence your random polynomials aren't independent --- then remove the dependent polynomial and replace it with a different random polynomial).

For example, let's use the four polynomials I used above as checkers, specialized to (say) $f_1(x) = 1, f_2(x) = 2x + 1, f_3(x) = x^2 + 1, f_4(x) = 5x^3 + 3x^2 - x + 1$. If we believe that the integral should be exactly given by a linear combination of the values of $f$ and $f'$ at $-1$ and $1$ (which I proved occurs from above), then we can try to find this linear combination from the linear system
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
f_1(-1) & f_1'(-1) & f_1(1) & f_1'(1) \\
f_2(-1) & f_2'(-1) & f_2(1) & f_2'(1) \\
f_3(-1) & f_3'(-1) & f_3(1) & f_3'(1) \\
f_4(-1) & f_4'(-1) & f_4(1) & f_4'(1) 
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\int_{-1}^1 f_1(x) dx \\
\int_{-1}^1 f_2(x) dx \\
\int_{-1}^1 f_3(x) dx \\
\int_{-1}^1 f_4(x) dx
\end{pmatrix},
$$
which specializes for my choices of polynomial above to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & -2 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 8 & 8 & 20
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{pmatrix}
= \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 8/3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Solving this system gives the solution $a = 1, b = 1/3, c = 1, d = -1/3$, which is exactly the answer $(2)$ above.

---

I rather like how the two solutions I describe are dual to each other, and how both actually end up being reduced to a game of linear algebra.

Comment: Thank you, great explain!

Comment: I just don't understand how do you get to the first matrix?

Comment: For example, let's compute the first row of the first matrix. This comes from $F(x) = Ax^3 + Bx^2 + Cx + D$, evaluated at $-1$. This is $F(-1) = -A + B - C + D$, whose coefficients are $(-1, 1, -1, 1)$. This is the first row of the matrix. The second row is from $F'(-1) = 3A - 2B + C$, whose coefficients are $(3, -2, 1, 0)$. And so on.